# How to Send Html Emails in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Here's an example of a Google Docs Spreadsheet script that sends emails using Google spreadsheets. I want the email Sent in HTML not plain text. Can someone help me out?

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the [documentation for MailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_mailapp#sendEmail). Assuming you have HTML code in the spreadsheet that you are loading into the `message` variable, you can specify an HTML body like so:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
```